# Overriding a Generated Partial Class

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have imported a third-party `WSDL` (via Service Reference) into my Console Application project in order to send and receive data through Web Services.  In order to get this to function appropriately, I have had to add some code to the `Reference.cs` file associated to the Web Service.  While this works, if an update is made to the WSDL, and I re-import/generate that Service Reference, that work-around code will go away.

In order to get around this, I have saved the necessary code-changes to an external text file saved within the project.

I'm curious if anyone knows of a way that I could write these changes into a their own separate class, outside of the Service Reference, and yet, still be referenced by the Service Reference, thus using the "correct" code needed to send/receive from the Web Service.

I have two classes (not included in the generated code) that I am able to reference in the generated code after separating them into their own `.cs` file and referencing the `namespace` used by the Service Reference.

What I would like to do, if possible, is the following:

---

**Overall Goal:**
*Add custom code to code generated by importing a third-party WSDL as a Service Reference, that way when the WSDL is updated by the third-party, another developer would not have to necessarily remember to dive into the `Reference.cs` file of the Service Reference, and replace/add specific code.*

**To achieve this goal, I need to be able to:**

1. Replace an existing property and associated field of the generated
   `partial class`, with a customized version (see Snippet #1 below).
2. Replace an existing generated `partial class` with a customized version of the class, having a different attribute definition and slightly different property/field definitions.

---

***Snippet #1***

Replace the following:

```
private byte[] bulkExchangeFileField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common", DataType = "base64Binary", Order = 0)]
public byte[] BulkExchangeFile
{
   get { return this.bulkExchangeFileField; }
   set
        {
            this.bulkExchangeFileField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("BulkExchangeFile");
        }
    }
```

with this version of the properties/fields that worked once I altered the generated code:

```
private BulkExchangeFileType bulkExchangeFileField;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common", Order = 0)]
public BulkExchangeFileType BulkExchangeFile
{
    get { return this.bulkExchangeFileField; }
    set
    {
        this.bulkExchangeFileField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("BulkExchangeFile");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use extension methods and/or overload the properties in an inhered class, so your code will not be replaced. 
To overload the properties you just need to declare it with the word new before public like in : `new public BulkExchangeFileType BulkExchangeFile`, so when you use the object it will call your properties instead the ones defined by the web service

and here is how to create extention methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383977.aspx

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InheredClass test = new InheredClass(); // Do this
        BaseClass test2 = new InheredClass(); // don't do this

        Console.WriteLine(test.MyProperty.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(test2.MyProperty.GetType());
        Console.Read();
    }


    class BaseClass
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    class InheredClass : BaseClass
    {
        new public decimal MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not sure I fully understand what you are saying about overloading the properties.  Would you be able edit your response in order to provide any examples/samples?  I want to replace one property with that of a different type: a property defined as `byte[]` with one defined as `BulkExchangeFileType`. I have updated my post with more specifics as to what I am looking for.